# How to pass querystring value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web application  we have show some products demo that we  are  developed  and i have stored that product details on database like

```
tblProduct{Id,ProductName,ProductDescription}
```

now suppose  User Click on Download link for Product A so on hyperLink of that page i have pass querystring like Demo Download
so it will redirect to that Inquiryform with ProductName is A  and  i have retrive that Querystring Value On that Inquiry Page  with code

```
 string productName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;
 objInquiry.InquiryFor = productName;
```

Now on next step  whenever User Press Submit Button On that inquiryForm one link should send to his Email ID  That Link is for Perticular that ProductOnly....now On code for Submit button i have Made Querystring like 
 `mail.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.abc.co.in/test.aspx?period=" + DateTime.Now + "&ProductName=[]\">Download Demo Software</a>";` now my question is how can i pass this productname  means   ProductName is A  so how can i pass this and how can i retrive this on test.aspx page..???pls help me

Comment: "Enquiry" is often preferred over "Inquiry" in this context... that's all I have to say about this question

Comment: Why are you using ProductName instead of Id? ProductName may not be unique, while ID is the PK of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the product name in like so:

```
mail.Body += string.Format("<a href=\"http:\//www.abc.co.in/test.aspx?period={0}&ProductName={1}\">Download Demo Software</a>", DateTime.Now, productName);
```

Retrieve it on `test.aspx` as normal :

```
string productName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;
```

Regarding your comment about file downloading, assuming your product has the filename field associated with it: -

```
string productName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
Product product = GetProductFromDB(productName);//I don't know what your DB access code looks like

//Build download link in markup:
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkFileDownload" runat="server" />

//Link code
lnkFile.NavigateUrl = string.Format("/FILE DOWNLOAD LOCATION/{0}/", product.FileName)
lnkFile.Text = "Download Demo Software";
```

Comment: You may need to escape the slashes, i've provided it as a verbatim string. I have edited it with escaped slashes for you...

Comment: sir on dubbing mode it will show both value date time and productname but in user's mail  it will not show hyperlink  means we have to close that anchor tag <a href=""></a>  sir so little mistake in that string pls solve it out .

Comment: Are you telling me you're unable to close an `<a>` tag yourself?

Comment: no i can  .......its  working  ..and  i m getting  url like http://www.abc.co.in/test.aspx?period=10/04/2013%203:09:39%20PM&ProductName=Apmc   ....now  what can i do ???how can i retrive on this test page?

Comment: In the code behind of your test page `test.aspx.cs`. Call `Request.QueryString["ProductName"]` to retrieve the product name from the url. To retrieve the full url, use `Request.RawUrl`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27930/discussion-between-purvang-pandya-and-dgibbs)

Comment: It depends on where you need to use the values? But yes, you could call that code from the page load.

Comment: okk next process  is that another filed for tblproduct is FileName and that is store in database and that download file is also have same name of that stored filename  suppose Product A has file name A.msi  and Demo for software A also has same Name A.msi  that user can download  now on that test page i have put setup of all product so what should be the code or query for that user only download that Demo for Product A

Comment: sir this is not diffrent question it is part of this question only  on final  stage of this process

Comment: Well not really, however I'll edit my answer to include this as it's straight forward enough.

Comment: sorry to say sir but  actully i m not geting anything from  your  code

Comment: Of course not, it's just a general concept as I have no idea what your product properties look like, or your db access code. This really is another question though and as such, I can't help you further with this until you start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question very well, but it seems to me that you have 3 pages.

- Page 1 where you have the hyperlink to download product A
- Page 2 where there is a Submit button (and a form, I suppose). In this page code behind you have: `string productName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;` . So you can create a hidden field in the form and add the ProductName.
- Page 3, you now can access ProductName using `Request.Form["ProductName"] as string;` and add the value to the email body.

**As I mentioned in my comment, I recommend you use ID, not ProductName.**

Comment: Sir But How can i pass Id on Frst page in querystring ???so i have pass productName